# force selectize.js only to show options that start with user input

Tags: javascript, user-interface, selectize.js

I am using selectize.js. Currently it looks like this:

[image]

It shows not only words that start with 'arm', but also words (or options) that contain 'arm' as a substring somewhere else.

I would like to force the function to show only those words (or options) that start with 'arm'.

I checked the usage documentation at https://github.com/selectize/selectize.js/blob/master/docs/usage.md but was not able to figure out how to solve this.

Does anybody have any ideas?

Comment: You may be able to do it with the `score` setting (you will find it in the docs at the link you provided in your question).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `score` property which loops through the entire list and sorts items. 1 being the most relevant one, 0 is considered as not matching, and the item is excluded. Knowing this we can write our own function :)

The score function is called each time a new character is entered. The inner function of score then checks each item, here's the structure of an item.

```
item = {
  text: 'Armband',
  value: 'Armband',
}
```

Knowing this we take `item.text`, make all letters lowercase *(remove `.toLowerCase()` if you don't want this)* and compare it with the value `search` *(also lowercase)*. When `item.text` starts with the value in `search`, then return 1 - item should be included - else 0 and the item is excluded from the list. Here's the entire function for `score`.

```
score: function(search) {
  var score = this.getScoreFunction(search);
  return function(item) {
    return item.text
      .toLowerCase()
      .startsWith(search.toLowerCase()) ? 1 : 0;
  };
},
```

Below is a working example to see it in action.

```js
if (!String.prototype.startsWith) {
  String.prototype.startsWith = function(search, pos) {
    return this.substr(!pos || pos < 0 ? 0 : +pos, search.length) === search;
  };
}

$('.select').selectize({
  placeholder: 'Maak een keuze',
  openOnFocus: true,
  items: [''],
  score: function(search) {
    var score = this.getScoreFunction(search);
    return function(item) {
      return item.text
        .toLowerCase()
        .startsWith(search.toLowerCase()) ? 1 : 0;
    };
  },
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/selectize.js/0.12.4/css/selectize.min.css">

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/selectize.js/0.12.4/js/standalone/selectize.min.js">
</script>

<select class="select" selected="">
  <option>Arm</option>
  <option>Armoede</option>
  <option>Armband</option>
  <option>Edeldarm</option>
  <option>Warmbloedig</option>
  <option>Opgewarmd</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Works well. I would like to know how to integrate this in a Shiny app. See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52039435/force-selectize-js-only-to-show-options-that-start-with-user-input-in-shiny

Comment: Your post mentions an inner `score` function, and your code has a reference to it, but the implementation does not call this function. What's up with that?