# force selectize.js only to show options that start with user input in Shiny

Tags: javascript, shiny, selectize.js

I am using selectizeInput in Shiny and would like to adapt this function so that only words starting with the characters entered by the user in the search field are shown in the option list. I look at the JavaScript code at:
[force selectize.js only to show options that start with user input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52003479/force-selectize-js-only-to-show-options-that-start-with-user-input/52009146#52009146) and tried the following:

```
library("shiny")

selectList <- sapply(1:10000, function(x) paste(sample(letters, 8), collapse = ''))

ui <- fluidPage(
  selectizeInput(inputId = 'mylist', label = 'Select something', choices = NULL, selected = 1),
  actionButton("search", "search"), br(), br(),
  textOutput("value")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
   updateSelectizeInput(session = session, inputId = 'mylist', choices = c(Choose = '', selectList), server = TRUE,
                       options = list(placeholder = "Select something", 
                                      dropdownParent = 'body', 
                                      openOnFocus = FALSE,
                                      items = c(),
                                      score = I("function(search) 
                                                 {
                                                   var score = this.getScoreFunction(search);
                                                   return function(item) 
                                                   {
                                                     return item.text
                                                     .toLowerCase()
                                                     .startsWith(search.toLowerCase()) ? 1 : 0;
                                                   };
                                                 }")
                       )
  )

  getValue <- eventReactive(input$search, { return(input$mylist) })
  output$value <- renderPrint({ return(getValue()) })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

but is does not work yet. Maybe I missed something simple, but does anybody know what should be changed in this code?

Comment: Hi Wilbert, thanks for bringing this to my attention. I've never worked with Shiny, so, I'm out of my comfort zone here. But looking at the code, it looks strange to put the whole store function in a function and within "". My first feeling was to chnage that. But then again, I'm unfamiliar with the syntax as is. Any chance this can be put up on GitHub so it can be tested locally?

Answer (score 0):

Solution: replace item.text by item label (thanks to jcheng, RStudio Community). I restructured the code a bit:

```
library("shiny")

selectList <- sapply(1:100000, function(x) paste(sample(letters, 8), collapse = ''))

ui <- fluidPage(
  selectizeInput(inputId = 'mylist', label = 'Select something', choices = NULL, selected = 1),
  actionButton("search", "search"), br(), br(),
  textOutput("value")
)

server <- function(input, output, session)
{
  getScore <- function()
  {
    return(I("function(search)
              {
               var score = this.getScoreFunction(search);
               return function(item)
                      {
                        return item.label
                        .toLowerCase()
                        .startsWith(search.toLowerCase()) ? 1 : 0;
                      };
              }"
            )
          )
  }

  updateSelectizeInput(session = session, inputId = 'mylist', choices = c(Choose = '', selectList), server = TRUE,
                       options = list(placeholder = "Select something", dropdownParent = 'body',
                                      openOnFocus = FALSE, items = c(), score = getScore()))

  getValue <- eventReactive(input$search, { return(input$mylist) })
  output$value <- renderPrint({ return(getValue()) })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```